# PHP For Loop - No Output After Loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a foreach loop, it's working fine - but for some reason anything out of the loop after it happens doesnt output. For example the echo $cpaTotal; doesn't display anything.

For loop prints out perfect

Where am I going wrong?

```
    $key = '84abf';
    $from = '2016/7/1';
    $to = '2016/9/17';
    $url = '/api/affreporting.asp?key='.$key.'&reportname=QuickSummaryReportDetailed&reportformat=xml&reportmerchantid=0&reportstartdate='.$from.'&reportenddate='.$to;
    $clean_xml = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', file_get_contents($url));
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml);
    $obj = json_decode(json_encode($xml));

    $cpaTotal = 'test';

    foreach($obj->Body->reportresponse->row as $row)
    {

        $CPACommission = $row->CPACommission;
        $merchant = $row->merchantname;
        $Product1NetRevenue = $row->Product1NetRevenue;

        echo "Merchant: ".$merchant. " | ";
        echo "CPA Commission: ".$CPACommission." | ";
        echo "Net Revenue: ".$Product1NetRevenue."</br>";
        echo "<hr>";

    }
    echo $cpaTotal;
```

Output (html)

```
Merchant: <strong>mFortune</strong> | CPA Commission: <strong> &pound;2270</strong> | Downloads: <strong>34</strong> | Net Revenue: <strong>&pound;-161.4</strong><br>Merchant: <strong>PocketWin</strong> | CPA Commission: <strong> &pound;1330</strong> | Downloads: <strong>22</strong> | Net Revenue: <strong>&pound;-134.77</strong><br>Merchant: <strong>Mr Spin</strong> | CPA Commission: <strong> &pound;680</strong> | Downloads: <strong>31</strong> | Net Revenue: <strong>&pound;13.22</strong><br>
```

Comment: You don't set $cpaTotal

Comment: I don't see why this shouldn't work and it also does not make any sense that it wouldn't. You need to provide us with a [mcve].

Comment: sorry just updated where   $cpaTotal = 'test'; is includuded

Comment: What is </br> for?

Comment: i have added full code - obviously URL won't work and I have had to change the key

Comment: _Just a Picky Point_: Why move data from a perfectly good property into a scalar variable to echo it?

Comment: I see no reason why this would not print the word `test` when you `echo $cpaTotal;`

Comment: Have you looked at the `page source` in the browser, to see if anything is echo'd just in case some HTML you are not showing us is getting in the way

Comment: I just thought it may of been easier to see my echo statements and try and find the problem - obviously that never worked out

Answer (score 1):

If you have the time and inclination to add a few extras to your code (just for debugging purposes), then you may want to try the code below. Note that there is essentially no big difference between the code below and yours except for the Fact that the Output was not instantly echoed out.

The only reason for this is so that you can simply comment out the `echo $output` Line to see if the `echo $cpaTotal` is displayed. If it displays, then that should be a Tip that there was a Swallowing of some of your HTML Markup coming from your Data (within the foreach Loop Block).

```
<?php

    $key        = '84abf';
    $from       = '2016/7/1';
    $to         = '2016/9/17';
    $url        = '/api/affreporting.asp?key='.$key.'&reportname=QuickSummaryReportDetailed&reportformat=xml&reportmerchantid=0&reportstartdate='.$from.'&reportenddate='.$to;
    $clean_xml  = str_ireplace(['SOAP-ENV:', 'SOAP:'], '', file_get_contents($url));
    $xml        = simplexml_load_string($clean_xml);
    $obj        = json_decode(json_encode($xml));               
    $cpaTotal   = 'test';
    $output     = '';

    foreach($obj->Body->reportresponse->row as $row){                   
        $CPACommission      = $row->CPACommission;
        $merchant           = $row->merchantname;
        $Product1NetRevenue = $row->Product1NetRevenue;

        // INSTEAD OF INSTANT ECHO,
        // TRY DELAYED ECHO BY HOLDING YOUR OUTPUT
        // INSIDE A VARIABLE LIKE THIS:                 
        $output .= "Merchant: "         . $merchant             . " | ";
        $output .= "CPA Commission: "   . $CPACommission        . " | ";
        $output .= "Net Revenue: "      . $Product1NetRevenue   . "</br>";
        $output .= "<hr>";                  
    }

    // BE ALSO AWARE THAT YOUR DATA CONTAINS RAW HTML...
    // SOMETIMES, UNCLOSED HTML TAGS OR SEMANTICALLY INACCURATE TAGS
    // COULD CAUSE A "SWALLOW" EFFECT.... WHICH MEANS, YOUR DATA IS ACTUALLY RENDERED
    // BUT NOT VISIBLE IN THE BROWSER DUE TO THE AFOREMENTIONED ERRORS.
    echo $output;
    echo $cpaTotal;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm going to try it now - I'm not to skilled with PHP but going to give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

`</br>` is not valid HTML, please use [`<br> or <br />`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp) to be HTML and XHMTL complient.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `<hr />` instead of just `<hr>` in the last line of your loop.

Comment: What about the </br>?

Comment: I've removed the <hr /> line completely, still no luck